# LinqtoSQL Getting a value from another table

Tags: c#, sql, linq

First time using LinqtoSQL.  So to give you guys a bit of context:

I have a simple SQL Server table called Inventory with the following fields

- InventoryID (int)(autoincrementing)
- InventoryItemName (varchar)(255)
- InventoryCategory (int)

Next I have another table called InventoryCategories for with the following fields:

- InventoryCategoryID (int)(autoincrementing)
- InventoryCategoryName (varchar)(255)
- InventoryCategoryDescription (varchar)(255)

Next,  Currently I have a combo box which selects which query to update the DataGrid.ItemSource,  The code fo for this is below

```
    if (searchcategory == "All Stock")
       {
          InventoryDataContext dc = new InventoryDataContext();

          var q =
                  from a in dc.GetTable<Inventory>()
                  select a;

                  SearchResults.ItemsSource = q;
       }
```

Now this result returns the Full table of Inventory with the columns of InventoryID, InventoryItemName, and InventoryCategory.  However it returns the ID Number of InventoryCategory, in the InventoryCategory Column.

Would anyone be able to help me get the InventoryCategoryName from InventoryCategories Table in this query instead of the ID?  What would be required for this?

Comment: You would need to join the two tables on the `InventoryCategoryID` and select a new type (may be anonymous) where you select the name instead of the full `Inventory` object. it would be adviseable to make a view which does that for you. Then you can simply query the view

Comment: Please, check the article, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause. Left outer join should fit your task well

Comment: you want InventoryCategoryName for selected InventoryID?

Comment: Hey guys,  thanks good information to get me started, QweRty - No I would like to return all results from Inventory Table, but instead of the Inventory Column of "InventoryCategory" (which stores numbers of the InventoryCategoryID as a FK),  I would like it to return the name of the category based on this Foreign Key ID Number

Comment: @Exxili We need to see dc.GetTable<Inventory>() code,because I think this is where Inventory and InventoryCategory table are joined or viewed or retrieved from db or ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using left join:

```
var qry = from inv in context.Inventory
          from invCategory in context.InventoryCategories.Where(u => inv.InventoryCategory == u.InventoryCategoryID).DefaultIfEmpty()
          select new myViewModel {id = invCategory.InventoryCategoryID, categoryName = invCategory .InventoryCategoryName  }
```

and don't forget to create myViewModel class with `id` and `categoryName` properties

Comment: This set me on the right path!  Got it working now :),  have also managed to create multiple left joins using this!  thank you Gusti!

Comment: @Exxili nice, glad to help you as well